# Problem in defining a function inside a module

Tags: functions, functional-style, debugging

I have a problem in defining a function in a module. I looked at Mathematica help and followed the same procedure.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
L = 4;
z1 = L/3;
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
A = 0.1^2;
kb = (Y*Iyy)/L^3;
\[Rho] = 7850;
W1 = A1*Sin[b*x] + B1*Cos[b*x] + C1*Sinh[b*x] + E1*Cosh[b*x];
W2 = A2*Sin[b*(x - z1)] + B2*Cos[b*(x - z1)] + C2*Sinh[b*(x - z1)] + 
   E2*Cosh[b*(x - z1)];
(*SS BC*)
(*CANTILEVER BC*)
bcd0 = W1 /. {x -> 0};
bcm0 = (D[W1, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 0};
bcdl = (D[W2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> L};
bcml = (D[W2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> L};

ccd1 = (W1 /. {x -> z1}) - (W2 /. {x -> z1});
ccs1 = ((D[W1, {x}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x}]) /. {x -> z1});
ccm1 = ((D[W1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1});
ccsh1 = ((D[W1, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[W2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z1}) - K*(W2 /. {x -> z1});

(*Forming matrix*)
R = Normal@
   CoefficientArrays[{bcd0, bcm0, bcdl, bcml, ccd1, ccs1, ccm1, 
      ccsh1}, {A1, B1, C1, E1, A2, B2, C2, E2}][[2]];
eq1 = FullSimplify[Det[R]];
f = Function[{K, b}, eq1]
f[3, 2](*Not working but why*)
g[K_, b_] := eq1;
g[3, 2](*Not working but why*)
c[x_] := x^2
c[4](*working but why*)
```

When I tried to write these functions inside a `Module` I started getting an error.  So I started writing outside the `Module` and found that my `Function` definition itself is not correct. I don't know where I am making a mistake. I don't know why the `Function` `f` and `g` cannot evaluated at `f[3,2]` and `g[3,2]`.

Answer (score 3):

`Attributes[Function]` contains `HoldAll`, which prevents the evaluation of `eq1` when the function is defined. When the function is called, `eq1` is evaluated after the argument replacements which is too late.

You could write

```
f = Function[{K, b}, Evaluate@eq1];
f[3, 2]
```

or

```
(f = Function[{K, b}, #]) &[eq1];
f[3, 2]
```

Note that `K` has a built-in meaning (dummy-variable for integrations, e.g. look at the output of `DSolve[y[x] == g[x] + y'[x], y , x]`) and should not be used as a variable.

Comment: Suppose if I want to convert one of the output into a function, say I get one of the output as eq1 which is having a dependency on k and b. And now i want to use eq1 to define a function? how to do that. Why the procedure  give in mathematica help is not working.

Comment: @vijay Then write `func = Function[{k, b}, Evaluate@Out[xxx]]`. Which procedure in the documentation do you talk about?

Comment: Go to Mathematica help and type defining Functions there are some example i followed those